# php - include() not finding path on remote server

Tags: php, wordpress, mpdf

I'm currently using mpdf to get content into a pdf file, this worked eprfectly until it got moved to a live server, in the header I have this piece of code:

```
44|    <?php 
45|    include('/mpdf/mpdf.php');
46|    ?>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Warning: include(/mpdf/mpdf.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/virtek/public_html/cherry/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/header.php on line 45

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/mpdf/mpdf.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php53/lib/php') in /home1/virtek/public_html/cherry/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/header.php on line 45
```

All the files are in the same place they were before migration.

This was working perfectly on the localhost, anyone got any idea of what could have happened or how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have a folder `mpdf` **in the root directory of your server**?! Not *web server*, but *server*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your files are in same location and structure then try:

```
<?php 
include('mpdf/mpdf.php'); // No slash
?>
```

The slash at the beginning on your original code tells the web server to look in the root for a directory called mpdf and then mpdf.php. This is because it is most likely a linux server.

Please see the following question [Relative path or absolute path and how to set up in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650517/relative-path-or-absolute-path-and-how-to-set-up-in-php)